# Combinatorics of binning data with repetitions

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

I'm trying to model random arrival times in discrete time bins.

Suppose I have $n$ (integer) arrival times, which are between $1$ and $m$, with $m$ possible time bins.  I randomly draw $n$ integers between $1$ and $m$, and I place every one of the (possibly alike) random numbers in the bin with its number.  Thus if I draw $\{1,5,9,5\}$, the bin count for this draw looks like $\{1,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,1,0\}$ and I call this a $\{2,1,1\}$ configuration.

What is the probability of finding a configuration $\{p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_n\}$, with $p_1\ge p_2\ge p_3$ *etc*, containing $p_1$ count in any bin, $p_2$ count in any other bin, and so forth until $p_n$ (which may or may not be $0$)?

For clarity I imagine I have $n=4$ arrival times and $m=10$ bins.  There are $10^4$ possible outcomes.  The probability of getting all different arrivals times is the number of permutations of a string like $\{0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4\}$, containing $4$ distinct symbols and $6$ other identical symbols.

This works out to $10\times 9\times 8\times 7=5040$ as I can choose to place $1$ in any of the $10$ slots, place $2$ in any of the remaining $9$ open slots etc.  Thus this type of outcomes occurs with probability $5040/10000$.

Now if I try to compute the probability of getting two like arrival times, and the remaining two arrivals times different - say I draw $\{1,8,2,8\}$ something like $\{0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,8,8\}$ - there are $10\times 9\times (8\times 7/2)=2520$ permutations of these.  The logic is simple: I can place my first symbol in any of the 10 empty bins, my second symbol in any of the remaining $9$ empty bins, and my like symbols in any of the remaining bins, but I must divide by $2$ because they are identical.

However, by running big numerical experiment where I randomly pick $4$-tuples between $1$ and $10$ and simply count the configurations, I find the correct number ought to be something like $10\times 9\times 8\times 6
= 10\times 9\times 8\times {4\choose 2}=4320$.  Not good.

The results of the computer simulation (for $10^5$ draws) are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \{1,1,1,1\} & 50371 \\
 \{2,1,1\} & 43076 \\
 \{3,1\} & 3690 \\
 \{2,2\} & 2772 \\
 \{4\} & 91 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

By hook or by crook I somehow produced the following table:
\begin{align}
\begin{array}{ccc}
\hbox{configuration}&\hbox{combinatorics}&\hbox{Prob}\\
\{1,1,1,1\}& 10!/6!&5040/10^4\\
\{2,1,1\}& 10\times 9\times 8\times {4\choose 2}&4320/10^4\\
\{3,1\}&10\times 9 \times {4\choose 3} & 360/10^4\\
\{2,2\}& 10\times 9 \times {4\choose 2}\times \frac{1}{2}& 270/10^4\\
\{4\} & 10 &10/10^4
\end{array}
\end{align}
The probabilities sum to $1$,  ($10^5\times$Prob) more or less matches the numbers of the simulation, and there's definitely a pattern but I'm defeated to understand how to generalize this to $n$ arrivals times in $m$ time bins.  It seems there is a prefactor which depends on the number of *distinct* symbols, and some combinatorial factor to account for identical entries.

However, trying to $n=5$ times in $m=10$ bins, it's not clear how to infer from the pattern how to compute the probability of the configuration $\{2,2,1\}$ arriving in $10$ different bins.

Since my "configurations" $\{p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_n\}$, with $p_1\ge p_2\ge p_3$ *etc* are similar to Young tableaux I thought counting tbut it's not clear at all how this would be useful.  Moreover the pattern for case of $n=4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have $n$ objects labelled $1,2, \cdots, n$, whose value ranges in $[1,m]$ and might be repeated.

A)  Disregarding the time sequence label, the different arrangements of the objects according to the value (frequency histogram)
correspond to the number of way of arranging $n$ undistinguishable objects into $m$ distinguishable bins, or which is the same
to the number of [weak compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28combinatorics%29) of
$n$ into $m$ parts, which is
$$\binom{n+m-1}{n}$$.
Asigning them the time labels correspond to make all the possible permutations of the $n$ objects which are $n!$
The total number thus comes out to be
$$
\left( \matrix{
  n + m - 1 \cr 
  n \cr}  \right)n! = {{\left( {n + m - 1} \right)^{\,\underline {\,n\,} } } \over {n!}}n! = \left( {n + m - 1} \right)^{\,\underline {\,n\,} }  = m^{\,\overline {\,n\,} } 
$$
However, this way of counting is making distinction among the histograms for

- different number of balls in each bin;
- different label of the balls in each bin;
- and as well, for different order of the ball labels in the bin .

For example, for two balls and two bins the $ 2^{\,\overline {\,2\,} } =6$ configurations are:
$$
 \eqalign{
  & \left( {\left. {\matrix{   a  \cr    b  \cr } } \right|\emptyset } \right),
 \;\left( {\emptyset \left| {\matrix{   a  \cr    b  \cr  } } \right.} \right),
 \;\left( {\left. a \right|b} \right),  \cr 
  & \left( {\left. {\matrix{   b  \cr    a  \cr  } } \right|\emptyset } \right),
 \;\left( {\emptyset \left| {\matrix{   b  \cr    a  \cr  } } \right.} \right),
 \;\left( {\left. b \right|a} \right) \cr} 
$$

B) Now consider the expansion of the multinomial of degree $n$ in $m$ variables
$$
\eqalign{
  & \left( {x_{\,1}  + \,x_{\,2}  + \, \cdots  + \,x_{\,m} } \right)^{\,n}
  = \left( {x_{\,1}  + \,x_{\,2}  + \, \cdots  + \,x_{\,m} } \right) \cdots \left( {x_{\,1}  + \,x_{\,2}  + \,
 \cdots  + \,x_{\,m} } \right) =   \cr 
  &  =  \cdots \; + x_{\,k_{\,1} } x_{\,k_{\,2} }  \cdots x_{\,k_{\,n} }  + \; \cdots \quad \left| {\;k_{\,j}
  \in \left\{ {1, \cdots ,\,m} \right\}} \right. =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{\left\{ {\matrix{   {0\, \le \,r_{\,j} \, \le \,n}  \cr    {r_{\,1}  + r_{\,2}  + \,
 \cdots  + \,r_{\,m} \, = \,n}  \cr  } } \right.}
 {\left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  r_{\,1} ,\,r_{\,2} ,\, \cdots ,\,r_{\,m}  \cr}  \right)x_{\,1} ^{\,r_{\,1} } x_{\,2} ^{\,r_{\,2} }
  \cdots x_{\,m} ^{\,r_{\,m} } }  \cr} 
$$

The second line tells you that you have all the possible sequences of $n$ elements from the set
$\{ {x_{\,1} ,\,x_{\,2} ,\, \cdots ,\,x_{\,m} } \} $ with repetition allowed (any, from $0$ to $n$).
The third lines gives you the number of ways to arrange the $n$ elements into a frequency histogram
with occupation profile  $\left( {r_{\,1} ,\,r_{\,2} ,\, \cdots ,\,r_{\,m} } \right)$, considered as an $m$-tuple, i.e.
occurring exactly in that order.
The expansion of the multinomial consists in picking one of the $m$ values from the first parenthesis, one from the second, etc.,
which corresponds to take ball No. $1$ and assign it to one of the $m$ bins, and same for the second till the $n$th.
In this process the balls enter each bin naturally ordered according to their timing label, and we do not distinguish
any more for the order inside a single bin.
The example $m=2,\, n=2$ now gives $m^n=4$ different arrangements as
$$
\left( {\left. {a,b} \right|\emptyset } \right),\;\left( {\emptyset \left| {a,b} \right.} \right),
 \;\left( {\left. a \right|b} \right),\;\left( {\left. b \right|a} \right)
$$
and
$$
 \left( \matrix{  2 \cr   2,\,0 \cr}  \right) = 1,
 \quad \left( \matrix{  2 \cr   0,\,2 \cr}  \right) = 1,
 \quad \left( \matrix{  2 \cr   1,\,1 \cr}  \right) = 2
$$
for each different $m$-tuple of the frequency profile.

C) The problem you pose is relevant to case B), but you are  interested not  just on a specific $m$-tuple,
yet in any permutation of a given $m$-tuple.

Let's order the representative $m$-tuple in an increasing way (multiset) and let's count how many of its elements have value $0,1,\cdots,n$
$$
\left( {r_{\,1} ,\,r_{\,2} ,\, \cdots ,\,r_{\,m} } \right)\; \Rightarrow \;
\left\{ {\underbrace {0, \cdots ,0}_{q_{\,0} }\;,\;\underbrace {1, \cdots ,1}_{q_{\,1} }\;,\,\; \ldots \;,
 \;\underbrace {n, \cdots ,n}_{q_{\,n\;} }\;} \right\}\quad \left| \matrix{
  \;0 \le q_{\,j}  \le n \hfill \cr 
  \;q_{\,0}  + q_{\,1}  +  \cdots  + q_{\,n}  = m \hfill \cr 
  \;0q_{\,0}  + 1q_{\,1}  +  \cdots  + nq_{\,n}  = n \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$

Now the number of ways to permute $n+1$ different objects, each replicated  $q_j$ times (null included) for a total of $m$  is just the multinomial coefficient $binom{m}{\bf q}$.

Therefore the required No. of ways would be
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\eqalign{
  & N = \left( \matrix{  n \cr   r_{\,1} ,\,r_{\,2} ,\, \cdots ,\,r_{\,m}  \cr}  \right)
 \left( \matrix{  m \cr   q_{\,0} ,q_{\,1} , \cdots ,q_{\,n}  \cr}  \right) =   \cr 
  &  = {{n!} \over {r_{\,1} !\,\;r_{\,2} !\,\; \cdots \,\;r_{\,m} !}}{{m!} \over {q_{\,0} !\;\;q_{\,1} !\;
  \cdots \;q_{\,n} !}} =   \cr 
  &  = {{n!} \over {r_{\,1} !\,\;r_{\,2} !\,\; \cdots \,\;r_{\,m} !\;0! \cdots 0!}}{{n!} \over {q_{\,0} !\;\;q_{\,1} !\;
  \cdots \;q_{\,n} !}} =   \cr 
  &  = {{n!} \over {\left( {0!} \right)^{\,q_{\,0} } \;\left( 1 \right)!\,^{\,q_{\,1} } \; \cdots \,\;
 \left( {n!} \right)^{\,q_{\,n} } }}{{m!} \over {q_{\,0} !\;\;q_{\,1} !\; \cdots \;q_{\,n} !}} \cr} 
 }$$

In your example  with $n=4, m=10$
$$
\eqalign{
  & \left\{ {1,1,1,1} \right\}\; \Rightarrow \;{\bf r} = \left( {0, \cdots ,0,1,1,1,1} \right)\;
 \Rightarrow \;{\bf q} = \left( {6,4,0, \cdots ,0} \right) \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \;N = {{n!} \over {\left( {0!} \right)^{\,6} \;\left( 1 \right)!\,^{\,4} }}{{m!} \over {6!\;\;4!\;}}
 = {{10!} \over {6!}} = 10^{\,\underline {\,4\,} }  = 5040  \cr 
  & \left\{ {1,1,2} \right\}\; \Rightarrow \;{\bf r} = \left( {0, \cdots ,0,1,1,2} \right)\; \Rightarrow \;{\bf q}
 = \left( {7,2,1, \cdots ,0} \right) \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \;N = {{n!} \over {\left( {0!} \right)^{\,7} \;\left( 1 \right)!\,^{\,2} \;\left( 2 \right)!\,^{\,1} }}
 {{m!} \over {7!\;\;2!\;\;1!\;}} = {{4!10!} \over {7!\, \cdot 4}} = 6 \cdot 10^{\,\underline {\,3\,} }  = 4320  \cr 
  & \left\{ {1,3} \right\}\; \Rightarrow \;{\bf r} = \left( {0, \cdots ,0,0,1,3} \right)\; \Rightarrow \;{\bf q}
 = \left( {8,1,0,1,0 \cdots ,0} \right) \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \;N = {{n!} \over {\left( {0!} \right)^{\,8} \;\left( 1 \right)!\,^{\,1} \;\left( 3 \right)!\,^{\,1} }}
 {{m!} \over {8!\;\;1!\;1!\;}} = {{4!10!} \over {3!\, \cdot 8!}} = 4 \cdot 10^{\,\underline {\,2\,} }  = 360  \cr 
  & \left\{ {2,2} \right\}\; \Rightarrow \;{\bf r} = \left( {0, \cdots ,0,0,2,2} \right)\; \Rightarrow \;{\bf q}
 = \left( {8,0,2,0 \cdots ,0} \right) \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \;N = {{n!} \over {\left( {0!} \right)^{\,8} \;\left( 2 \right)!\,^{\,2} }}{{m!} \over {8!\;\;2!\;}}
  = {{4!10!} \over {4 \cdot 2\, \cdot 8!}} = 3 \cdot 10^{\,\underline {\,2\,} }  = 270  \cr 
  & \left\{ 4 \right\}\; \Rightarrow \;{\bf r} = \left( {0, \cdots ,0,0,4} \right)\; \Rightarrow \;{\bf q}
 = \left( {9,0,0,0,1,0 \cdots ,0} \right) \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \;N = {{n!} \over {\left( {0!} \right)^{\,9} \;\left( 4 \right)!\,^{\,1} }}{{m!} \over {9!\;\;1!\;}}
 = {{4!10!} \over {4! \cdot 9!}} = 1 \cdot 10^{\,\underline {\,1\,} }  = 10  \cr 
  & {\rm Tot} = 10000 = m^{\,n}  \cr} 
$$

Comment: yeah this works.  I found a solution yesterday and yours looks like its more amenable to analysis.

Comment: ... and it's more elegant also :)

Comment: glad it helped ! and thanks to you fro proposing such an interesting problem!